# How to set wickedpicker time on a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wickedpicker

I have some wickedpicker elements that are initialized as such:

```
var timepickers = $('.timepicker').wickedpicker({'twentyFour': true, 'clearable':true});
```

I would like to change the default time and set clearable to false based on some db information but I'm not sure how to do this for specific elements. Here's what I've been trying:

```
$("#monday").wickedpicker({'clearable': false, 'now':"14:00",'timeSeparator': ':'});
```

But this hasn't been working. What am I doing wrong?